How do I use cshtml links inside a controller class?
I have an older ASP.NET Core 2.1 web app project.
I have a .cshtml page in this folder in my project:
G:\Projects\AccessApp\Pages\Privacy.cshtml

And I want to use it in my controller. I've tried the following paths, but none work:
~/Pages/Privacy.cshtml
./Pages/Privacy.cshtml
../Pages/Privacy.cshtml
/Pages/Privacy.cshtml
Pages/Privacy.cshtml

Here is where I'm trying to put it inside the controller:
[Route("Login")]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "~/Pages/Privacy.cshtml")
{
    // ...
}

Is there anything I can do to get this to work?
Thanks!

look for the Redirect methods.

@DanielA.White Hi Daniel, I looked and I could not find that in my code.  I just have the returnUrl  thanks!

What type of controller are you using as the base class?

@DanielA.White It just says Controller like this: public class AuthController : Controller

Instead of providing the page path, would suggest making it as a route path. For example:
[Route("Login")]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "Privacy")
{
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}

Also, you need to implement the controller action for your page:
[Route("Privacy")]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    return View();
}

By default, the controller (action) maps with the (.cshtml) page in the Views, Views/Shared, and Pages folders. If you want to work with the other directory, you need to work with ViewLocationExpander. Reference: Expanding Razor View Location And Sub Areas In ASP.NET Core

Implement the IViewLocationExpander class:

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;

public class CustomViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context
        , IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        // Custom view locations
        var customLocations = new[]
        {
            "/Pages/{0}.cshtml",
        };

        return customLocations.Concat(viewLocations);
    }
}

You can specify the extra page that is needed with {0} placeholder is for the action name, and {1} is for the controller name.

In the ConfigureServices method (Startup.cs), configure Razor View Options:

services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorOptions(opts =>
    {
        opts.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new CustomViewLocationExpander());
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

But note that with this implementation, it may replace the page in the mentioned 3 folders. Hence, you need to avoid the file in your additional folder having the conflict name in the default directory. Or modify the file name, create a special name for the directory for your additional folder file to make it as unique (route/path).
